# setimeout is calling multiple times on double click of button in angular

Tags: angular

settimout function is calling multiple times on double click of button. But when using clear timeout initially data is not loading because of clear timeout function

```js
var intervalID =  setTimeout(() => {
 for(var i= 0;i<this.scoutrowdataList.length-1;i++){
    for(var j= 0;j<this.uniqueArray.length;j++){
    //code for looping
    }
 }
        
}, 1000);
clearTimeout(intervalID)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using setTimeout here? If you are trying to prevent double click from interfering with you first click look at debounce in https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce or you can always use clearTimeout inside the setTimeout function immediately after the loop completes. or clearTimeout at the beginning of a function start so that the function will execute but will clear the previous request or just return from the func if intervalId is not null.

Comment: The purpose of set time out is data from Api is not returning fastly.so i use set timeout function. Now i changed  var   intervalID =  setTimeout(() => {
 for(var i= 0;i<this.scoutrowdataList.length-1;i++)
 {
  for(var j= 0;j<this.uniqueArray.length;j++){
//code for looping }}
clearTimeout(intervalID)
}, 1000);still no result

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXBqC.png.This is image of my issue

Comment: Please minimise and paste the code for the logic.